# Commit file to github and then unstage because it contains sensitive data

Tags: git, oauth, commit, stage

I"m trying to work on a Twitter Github project. I have an OAuth class that I want uploaded once to give the layout for OAuth, however after that I dont want it to be committed anymore so I can put my data in it and not have it uploaded. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use update-index to tell git that it should always assume that file is never changed:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged oath.class
```

You can toggle it back by using --no-assume-unchanged

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged oath.class
```

Which will make git notice changes to the file again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .gitignore to ignore certain files in future commits. See http://book.git-scm.com/4_ignoring_files.html

Comment: You could also ignore the file from the very beginning and force the 'template' in with `git add --force myFile`

Comment: Didn't know that parameter. Very useful.